# How to get current product attributes on product view page using widget

Tags: product, widget

I have bought a theme that allows a custom tab in product view. It uses a static block for this. Now I have some products that come with documentation in pdf format. I was thinking I want to add links to the documentation in that custom tab. So I've created widgets before and I thought the easiest way was to create a widget that puts out the links, and place it in the static block used for the custom tab. That way I don't have alter theme files.

Now I managed to create the widget and have it render in the custom tab. So far so good. Now I want to display the links to the pdf's (which I have as a product attribute), but I can't find a way to get the current product's attributes (that is the product viewed on the frontend) within the widget (class).

I would like to know a way to get the id or model of the product being viewed, or something alike, so I can get the product attributes. This, of course, within the widget class.

I am currently using Magento CE 1.9.1.1

Some thoughts on this? I have searched the deepest of the interwebs but wasn't able to find anything. Hope someone can get me on the right track.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply run the following code. No need to load the product using request parameters, because the product model should already be initiated and loaded:

```
if(Mage::registry('current_product')) { //check if product global 'registry' object is available
    $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
    $name = $product->getName(); //etc
}
```

If you're loading the product model twice, you will use twice the resources.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more digging and found out it's quite simple:

First I check whether or not on a product page, if so then load the product:

```
if(Mage::registry('current_product')) { // <-- check if on product page
    $productId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id'); // <-- get current product Id
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId); // <-- Load product
}
```

Comment: No need to load the product, `Mage::registry('curent_product')` should already be a product object